# filter/map structure to map/guard structure in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, dictionary, filter

I have a `summaryPool` mutable map that maps a String to a Summary object. 
The function `namesToSummary` has two parameters, the first one is a series of names (in Iterable[String]), and the second one is the summaryPool. What it does is that it returns a series of Summary that **corresponds** the names.

It's a little bit more complicated, as the name should be checked using regular expression to extract the information that used to be the key to the summaryPool.

For example, "summary1b" should be checked to get "summary1" and "b"; the "summary1" is the key to the pool. In some cases, there may not be the "b" appended.

My implementation uses `isSummaryPool` function to filter out wrongly formatted name, or the name that is not in the pool. Then, I use map to get the copy of Summary object in the pool.

```
  import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => mm}
  def namesToSummaries(names: Iterable[String], summaryPool: mm[String, Summary]) = {
    val namePattern = """([a-zA-Z]+\d+)([a-z])?""".r
    def inSummaryPool(name: String) = {
      name match {
        case namePattern(summaryName, summaryType) => {
          if (summaryPool.contains(summaryName)) true
          else false
        }
        case _ => false
      }
    }

    names filter inSummaryPool map { name =>
      name match {
        case namePattern(summaryName, summaryType) => {
          var sType = summaryType
          if (sType == null || !(sType == "b" || sType == "l")) sType = "b"
          summaryPool.get(summaryName).get.copy(sType)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It works fine, but I don't like the implementation as it checks regular expression matching twice.

I think I can integrate the filter/map into map with guard. In order to do so, I thinK I may need to implement similar to this:

```
  import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => mm}
  def namesToSummaries(names: Iterable[String], summaryPool: mm[String, Summary]) = {
    val namePattern = """([a-zA-Z]+\d+)([a-z])?""".r

    names map { name =>
      name match {
        case namePattern(summaryName, summaryType) => {
          if (summaryPool.contains(summaryName)) {
            var sType = summaryType
            if (sType == null || !(sType == "b" || sType == "l")) sType = "b"
              summaryPool.get(summaryName).get.copy(sType)
          }
          else 
            ???
        }
        case _ => ???
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure what expression should be given in ??? to teach Scala to ignore these cases.

What might be the solution?

### EDIT1

I can think about making a ListBuffer object to add Summary object when necessary.
But, I'm not sure about the case when the pattern does not match.

```
    val list: ListBuffer
    names foreach { name =>
      name match {
        case namePattern(summaryName, summaryType) => {
          if (summaryPool.contains(summaryName)) {
            var sType = summaryType
            if (sType == null || !(sType == "b" || sType == "l")) sType = "b"
              list += summaryPool.get(summaryName).get.copy(sType)
          }
        }
        case _ => ???
      }
    }
  }
```

#### EDIT2

From Shadowlands' answer, flatMap with None return works fine.

```
def namesToSummaries(names: Iterable[String], summaryPool: mm[String, Summary]) = {
    val namePattern = """([a-zA-Z]+\d+)([a-z])?""".r
    names flatMap { name =>
        name match {
            case namePattern(summaryName, summaryType) => {
                if (summaryPool.contains(summaryName)) {
                    var sType = summaryType
                    if (sType == null || !(sType == "b" || sType == "l")) sType = "b"
                    Some(summaryPool.get(summaryName).get.copy())
                }
                else None
            }
            case _ => None
        }
    }
}
```

#### EDIT3

From Jilen's hint, `collect` seems to be the good answer to reduce more lines of code.

```
def namesToSummaries(names: Iterable[String], summaryPool: mm[String, Summary]) = {
    val namePattern = """([a-zA-Z]+\d+)([a-z])?""".r
    names collect { name =>
        name match {
            case namePattern(summaryName, summaryType) if (summaryPool.contains(summaryName)) => {
                var sType = summaryType
                if (sType == null || !(sType == "b" || sType == "l")) sType = "b"
                  summaryPool.get(summaryName).get.copy()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this code in IntelliJ 14 shows false positive error: this is a bug report (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9094#).

Comment: I think you should use `collect` , it may smplified as [this](https://gist.github.com/jilen/147ac57d71b9bb5dd388)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `map` on the names, try using `flatMap`. Wrap your successful cases in `Some(...)`, and the `???` becomes `None`. The 'flattening' part of the flatMap will reduce the 'mapped' `Iterable[Option[String]]` back to an `Iterable[String]`, ditching all the `None` cases.

**Edit**: I didn't drill into your code quite carefully enough - in the 'successful' case you appear to be doing pure side-effecting stuff (ie. updating the mutable map), not returning a result of any kind.

You could instead return a `(summaryName, summaryType)` tuple at this point (wrapped in `Some`) and apply the side-effecting code to the contents of the resulting `flatMap` (probably my preference as being a slightly more functional style), or simply go back to using map and just write `_` (meaning here: 'do nothing - ignore any result') instead of `???`.